# Реализовать циклический сдвиг массива на 1 элемент вправо или влево.

Tags: массивы, c

Написать функцию:

```
void arrayShiftRight(int array[], int size)
```

**Дополнено**:

Сделал сдвиг влево, но что-то не так:

```
void arrayShiftLeft(int array[], int size) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++ ) {
        array[i-1] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал сдвиг влево но что то не так:

void arrayShiftLeft(int array[], int size) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++ ) {

        array[i-1] = array[i];

    }

}

Comment: Так просто сдвиг или циклический сдвиг?

Comment: Циклический сдвиг.

Comment: 1. Элемента с индексом -1 просто нет. Туда писать нельзя. Крайний левый `array[0]`.
2. Его надо запомнить, а в конце (после цикла) записать вместо последнего (`array[size-1]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Циклический сдвиг вправо

```
  void arrayRotateRight(int array[], int size) {
    register int temp = array[--size];        
    while ( size > 0 ) array[size--] = array[size-1];    
    array[0] = temp;
  }
```

Циклический сдвиг влево

```
  void arrayRotateLeft(int array[], int size) {
     register int i, temp = array[0];
     for (i = 0, size--; i < size; i++) array[i] = array[i+1];
     array[size] = temp;
  }
```

Comment: А зачем register? Что он делает.

Comment: Рекомендует компилятору локализовать эту переменную в регистре процессора для ускорения работы с ней. Можно, есно, без него.

Comment: У меня при тестировании массив за пределы вылазит (( Program returned 139 during test.


  
  void arrayShiftLeft(int array[], int size) {
     int temp = array[0];
    
     for ( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++, size-- ) {
         array[i] = array[i+1];
         array[size] = temp;
     }
 }

Comment: Надо писать

  array[size-1] = temp;

Answer (score 3):

"Эта манишка, эти завязочки от кальсон... Проще надо одеваться, Паниковский!"
Что-то вы, братцы, декрементами себя измучили.
Действительно, вначале запоминаем a[0].

```
 int a[10];
 const int size = 10;//Это размер массива 
 const int temp = a[0];
 //А потом, сдвиг влево на 1 значение
 for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
   a[i-1] = a[i];
//и, наконец,
 a[size-1] = temp;
```

Все, и никаких декрементов :)

Comment: А мне так нравится.

Comment: Понимаете, очень часто в программировании одна и та же проблема может быть решена несколькими способами, часто по эффективности не различающимися. Что выбрать - дело вкуса. И не нужно свои вкусы навязывать другим.

Comment: Да я не о вкусах Вам говорю, а про Ваши ошибки, уважаемый @mikillskegg

Comment: Конкретно - о каких. Я протестировал свой код, все работает. То, что Вы написали, - то же самое, только немного другими словами.

Comment: Просто и понятно, как раз для человека у которого возник такой вопрос.

Comment: Я дал ему пищу для размышлений. Пусть сидит и думает, разбирает, может, что и поймет. Все, что я написал, основано на элементарном синтаксисе. Ничего сверхчеловеческого в нем нет.